# How to change cursor shape of QPlainTextEdit (Pyqt, PySide)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a simple Qt widget contains of a `QPlainTextEdit`. I only want to display text so I disabled text interaction. Now I want to change the cursor shape to the normal `Qt.ArrowCursor`. I tried:

```
self.disp = QPlainTextEdit()
self.disp.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.NoTextInteraction)
self.disp.setCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor)
```

but it doesn't work.

PS: I don't want to use:

```
QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))
```

as I actually have other widgets in the application and I don't want to affect them.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the solution. For the information of thoes who googled here, `viewport()` is inherited from `QAbstractScrollArea`. So this method is applicable for all the subclasses under `QAbstractScrollArea`, see here:[link](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QAbstractScrollArea.html#PySide.QtGui.QAbstractScrollArea)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try set cursor to viewport() of QPlainTextEdit.

```
viewport().setCursor();
```